# Change color of specific part in an image

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I have a question about how to change specific part of an image by flutter or unity
I made a button to open camera and take a photo then I need to change the sky color only "an example"
how could I do that to use it on a project that will be made by flutter and unity
for another example see the image in the following link
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN3kq.jpg

Comment: The example you show swaps the Cr and Cb chroma channels of the image; that's an easy image manipulation. On the other hand, to 'change the sky color' is a big task, because you first need to find the pixels that belong to that sky, and decide how you change them, and what you do to make the seam between the recolored sky and the rest of the image, to look natural.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For simple color change, you can use [ShaderMask](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ShaderMask-class.html):

```
ShaderMask(
  shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
    return RadialGradient(
      center: Alignment.topLeft,
      radius: 1.0,
      colors: <Color>[Colors.yellow, Colors.deepOrange.shade900],
      tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
    ).createShader(bounds);
  },
  child: /* your image */,
)
```

[reference](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/shadermask-in-flutter-706d9948eb90)